# After running the script it displays nothing just blank screen and there are no errors

Tags: php

Blank screen appears and there are no errors below is the code connection is also fine can't identify the issue as well as checked with scripts available on internet data is been inserted via that script.

Inserted all the parameters [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvue2.png)

```
<?php
 include_once 'connection.php';
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  class user{
      private $db;
      private $connection;

      function __construct(){
            $this -> db = new DB_Connection();
            $this -> connection = $this->db->getConnection();   //to connect to database      
      }

      public function register($email,$phoneno,$fname,$lname,$gender,$password){

         $query = "insert into register(email, phoneno, fname, lname, gender, password) values ( '$email','$phoneno','$fname','$lname','$gender','$password')"; //insertion
          $inserted = mysqli_execute($this -> connection,$query);
          if($inserted == 1){
              $json['success'] = 'Account created';
          }else{
              $json['failure'] = 'wrong password';
          }
          echo json_encode($json);
          mysqli_close($this -> connection);
            }


  }
  $nuser = new user();
  if(isset($_POST['email'],$_POST['phoneno'],$_POST['fname'],$_POST['lname'],$_POST['gender'],$_POST['password'])){
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $phoneno = $_POST['phoneno'];
      $fname = $_POST['fname'];
      $lname = $_POST['lname'];
      $gender = $_POST['gender'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      if(!empty(email)&& !empty(password)){
          $nuser->register($email,$phoneno,$fname,$lname,$gender,$password);
      }else{
          echo json_encode("fill all fields");
      }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Like Akshay claimed, make sure your errors are enabled either in your configuration or by manually setting them on the file.

Comment: It's this an ajax request?

Comment: You forgot $ sign in inner `if` condition.

Comment: after making some changes it given o/p as mysqli_execute() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given on line 16 what will be the possible issue ??

Answer (score 0):

try `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` on the top of the page.  Might be error display is disabled.

I think the problem is in this line.

```
if(!empty(email)&& !empty(password)){
```

you forgot `$` sign

Comment: This isn't an answer and should be posted as a comment.

Comment: Inserted the $ sign but same displays nothing and where to post ini_set("display_errors", 1) i don;t much about php :P

Comment: on the top of your page

Comment: after inserting it shows :<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 'include_once' (T_INCLUDE_ONCE) in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\1\a.php</b> on line
<b>3</b>
<br />

Comment: and don't think its an issue because jst importing the file

Comment: I think you missed semicolon after `ini_set` statement.

Comment: ya added semicolon then 2 same response :( any way i can check my connection is that droping

Comment: after making some changes it given o/p as mysqli_execute() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given on line 16 what will be the possible issue ?? @AkshayPrakash

Comment: mysqli_execute accepts only query. No need to pass connection object